# How to save the drawing (contents) on a panel as an image using C# and asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How to save the drawing (contents) on a panel as an image using C# and asp.net.I found Panel1.DrawToBitmap but its not working in the asp.net ,is there any assembly i am missing or the function is all together different ?

```
 int width =Convert.ToInt32(Panel1.Width);
    int height = Convert.ToInt32(Panel1.Height);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width,height);       
    Panel1.DrawToBitmap//no definition or missing assembly
```

Any help or suggestion will help me a lot.

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What drawing/content? Where does it come from?

Comment: @oded .. I am actually dropping some images on the panel, like cars/roads.. Then i want to save that panel as Image in database.

Comment: Where are you dragging them from? Do they actually show up on the panel?

Comment: I am dragging them from a div and dropping on the other panel. Bacially creating  a diagram . Then i want to save all these images inside the panel as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DrawtoBitmap is a windows forms method.  I don't believe there is a asp.net equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a web page it depends on what kind of browser is rendering the HTML that your ASP page renders. If your'e interested in how your web page looks in different browsers, http://browsershots.org/ is a fun page.

Otherwise I guess you could try to render the HTML yourself and draw that to a Bitmap.